# EAR file could not be deployed in Weblogic 10

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, weblogic

I'm using weblogic 10.3.5. Since my last svn update I can't deploy a ear file. In the server console on eclipse I have the error log :

```
Deployment connection was released before the state of deployment was known.
```

The complete exception stacktrace :

```
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:190)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:510)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1501)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:920)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:708)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3153)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

I have the same settings than my co workers, the same code except few javascript code unrelated. I've already tried lots of tips : clean my weblogic server, clean all project in my workspace, update all project maven dependencies.

Any idea?

Comment: And what says Error Log View?

Comment: Did you tried to increase the deployment timeouts in your server runtime configuration? In eclipse in the server view, right click on the desired server, select open. Then you get the server configuration page, there is a section about timeout and how eclipse recordnizes deployments etc.. Try to increase this values. Because your error is saying something about lost connection, which can happen when a timeout reached. Do you have a virus scanner running? Try to disable him to increase deployment time and to reduce IO path in OS.

Comment: @Olexd : Error log view just says what I've written, the complete stacktrace is when I double click on the error : "Deployment connection was released before the state of deployment was known.".

Comment: @Rene M. : I've tried it but I still have the same error message. It doesn't take that much time to start and deploy anyway : maybe 45 seconds and the timeout was already way longer at about 5 minutes. I change it to 8 minutes.

Comment: Then my last two ideas: 1. Virus scanner, make an exclude for eclipse and the app server. 2. Create a new server configuration in eclipse

Comment: Thanks for your help. It doesn't work better but I learn few things! I can't do anything on the virus scanner but I'm pretty sure it's not the problem. I re create the server but it's the same configuration : still : same weblogic home and same Domain directory. I've deleted the edit.lock in the domain directory but I still have the same error.

Comment: Is that the full stack trace? Other users with a similar problem have larger stack trace like https://community.oracle.com/thread/3634908 Can you deploy the ear file manually?